# Python join 2 char into the same short

Tags: python, casting, char, short

I would like to do 2 char into a short.

I want to do that (c syntax):

```
short var = (msg[4:5]<<8) | (msg[5:6])
```

algo:

```
ord(msg[4:5) = 105 -> 0b1101001

ord(msg[5:6) = 135 -> 0b10000111

var =  0b1101001 <<8        eq 0b1101001 00000000      eq 0x6900

var |= 0b10000111           eq 0b1101001 10000111      eq 0x6987

var = 27015
```

So i want as result the a numeric value
If you have any solution...
Thanks

Comment: And what is the problem exactly? Did that not work in Python? What errors did you see?

Comment: You already have found the needed syntax elements: `ord()`, `|` and `=`. What else do you need?

Comment: note there is no such thing as a short in Python

Comment: Try the struct module: `num=struct.unpack('>h',str)`

Comment: @thg435 good idea but this looks like homework to me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
(ord(msg[4])<<8) + ord(msg[5])
```

Comment: Psychic debugging FTW. You can use `|` as well instead of `+`.

Comment: Actually, using either `msg[4]` or `msg[4:5]` doesn't matter on strings, so either way would work. The OP is not really asking a question yet either.